# Aptana command to create file from template

Tags: templates, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

I am looking for a way to create a new file from a template by invoking a dedicated shortcut.

As far as I understand Aptana, I should do two things:

1. create my own template, which I did.
2. create a command that creates a new file based on this template

I know how to create commands in Aptana, but I don't know how the make the command do what I want in this specific case.

Can this be done? Does anybody know how?